# Is it possible to copy xpath in google or chrome without tbody tags?

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data in an old website that use only tables without any class or id identification. When I use copy xpath function in Chrome or Firefox they return something like this to me:

`/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/font`

These `tbody` tags seems unreachable to Python's Scrapy, and the chaotic nature of the site's html structure makes almost impossible for me to create an xpath myself. Is there any way I can copy the xpath without these `tbody` tags?

Comment: Have you tried removing `tbody/` from the expressions?

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: @zx485 thank you so much!!!! I just removed the tags and everything worked as intended!